# Setting up IIS7 as a basic web host (website w/ attached ftp site)

Tags: iis-7, ftp

Am I becoming a lazy researcher? If I don't find good answers via Google, instead of continuing to try various research methodologies, here I am at SO again...

I want to host a few websites on IIS7 on Windows Server 2008. I am familiar with how to setup/configure the website. What I would like to do is setup a ftp site for each website allowing a specific user to manage the files for that site. I do not understand enough of how to administer the new FTP server and do not know the best practices for how to setup the security for the directory/website/ftpsite.

Does anyone have experience in this area or know of any good online resources?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the old IIS6 interface to setup FTP websites. Then you set permissions on directories as you would for regular file system access. I don't really like this very much, but it does the job.

Comment: Microsoft has released a new FTP server for IIS7 (at least on Windows Server 2008) that integrates with IIS7 MMC, etc.